# What syllable is stressed in "complex"?

Tags: pronunciation, stress

I've read somewhere that if *complex* is an adjective, its second syllable is stressed (com-**plex**), while for noun, the first one (**com**-plex). But e.g. [this link](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/complex) says that adjective can also sound as noun. I also remember that my teacher (many years ago) said "**com**-plex object", although *complex* is an adjective here.

I guess stress depends on context of usage. So, what are the cases for stressing first or second syllable in adjective *complex*? How do I determine which syllable has to be stressed?

For example, how are "complex numbers", "complex object", "complex problem" pronounced?

Comment: What have you found in modern dictionaries?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the second syllable being stressed in adjectival usages. I put stress on the first syllable in *all* contexts.

Comment: In my speech, if *complex* is a noun, the stress is on the first syllable. If *complex* is an adjective, the primary stress is on the first syllable, but there is also secondary stress on the second syllable. So /ˈkɑm.plɪks/ for the noun and /ˈkɑmˌplɛks/ for the adjective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OED has accent on *com* for both noun and adjective, but accent on *plex* for verb.  **What verb,** you ask.  Well, it is obsolete or rare except in chemistry, where it means "form a complex with".

> These hormones must complex with specific receptors in order to...

Here in America, I have heard the *plex* accent version on occasion.  But nothing as simple as the noun/adjective distinction proposed by Ruslan.

My American dictionary has only *com* accent for the noun, but both possible accents for the adjective or the verb.

My advice: use accent *com* for the adjective, no one will object (or even notice).

Note: combined forms may accent the *plex* ... **complexity, complexification, non-complex, super-complex**.

Comment: I tend to stress the first syllable when I use *complex* attributively (*Korea has a complex history*) and on the second when predicatively (*The history of Korea is as fascinating as it is complex*); as a noun or verb, I always stress the first with a secondary stress on the second.

Comment: @choster Yes. I have to agree, having listened to it that some people (definitely a minority) do put the emphasis on the 'plex'. I am sorry to have misinformed everyone. I have therefore deleted my earlier comment.

Comment: Oxford's OALD has both stress versions accepted for NAmE: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/complex_1?q=complex